# If $f$ and $g$ are continuous in $[a, b]$, and $f(a)=g(b)$ and $f(b)=g(a)$, then $f$ and $g$ intersect in $[a,b]$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

> The functions $f,g$ are continuous in $[a, b]$, and they satisfy the properties:
>
> $$f(a) = g(b) \\
> f(b) = g(a)$$
>
> Show that $f$ and $g$ intersect in the interval $[a,b]$.

My attempt:

Let $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$. Because of the previous definitions we have that without loss of generality that $h(a) \leq 0 \leq h(b)$. It follows that $h$ is continuous. By the definition of continuity there is a $c$ in the interval such that $h(c) = 0$. Therefore rearranging $f(c) = g(c)$ and the proof is complete.

> Does this work or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, let $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ then we get:
$$h(a)=f(a)-g(a)=f(a)-f(b)\\ 
  h(b)=f(b)-g(b)=f(b)-f(a)
$$
Therefore $h(a)=-h(b)$.
Since $h$ is continous, we know 
$$\exists c\in[a,b]\ \ s.t \ \ h(c)=0\implies f(c)=g(c)$$

Almost identical to your proof, without using WLOG.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!